# Find pixel coordinates from lat/long point in .geotiff using python and gdal

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff, osgeo

I have (lat,long) coordinate describing the position of a point in a .geotiff image.

I wish to find the equivalent pixel coordinates of the lat,long ones inside the image.

I succeded using gdaltransform from the command line with the following instruction :

```sh
gdaltransform -i -t_srs epsg:4326 /path/imagename.tiff
-17.4380493164062 14.6951949085676
```

But i would like to retrieve such type of equivalence from python code. I tried the following :

```py
from osgeo import osr

source = osr.SpatialReference()
source.ImportFromUrl(path + TIFFFilename)

target = osr.SpatialReference()
target.ImportFromEPSG(4326)

transform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(target,source )

point_xy = np.array(transform.TransformPoint(-17.4380493164062,14.6951949085676))
```

But it returns this error :

```py
NotImplementedError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'CoordinateTransformation_TransformPoint'.
  Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
    OSRCoordinateTransformationShadow::TransformPoint(double [3])
    OSRCoordinateTransformationShadow::TransformPoint(double [3],double,double,double)
```

What am i doing wrong ? I tried to work around this error but without any success. Is there an other way to do it ?

**EDIT 1 :**

I achieved a single transformation via gdaltransform commands in terminal :

```
gdaltransform -i -t_srs epsg:4326 /path/image.tiff
-17.4380493164062 14.6951949085676
```

As i need to retrieve the pixel in a pythonic way, i tried calling the command using subprocess like :

```py
# TRY 1:
subprocess.run(['gdaltransform','-i',' -t_srs','epsg:4326','/pat/img.tiff\n'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
# TRY 2 :
cmd = '''gdaltransform -i -t_srs epsg:4326 /home/henri/Work/imdex_visio/AllInt/Dakar_X118374-118393_Y120252-120271_PHR1A_2016-03-10T11_45_39.781Z_Z18_3857.tiff
-17.4380493164062 14.6951949085676'''
subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

But it does not work. Maybe because of the way the command itself behaves, like not actually returning a result and ending itself, but displaying the result and staying busy.

Comment: Have your tried just parsing a third argument to TransformPoint? Like `transform.TransformPoint(-17.4380493164062, 14.6951949085676, 0)`

Comment: Can you check GDAL version? It might be that in an older implementation of python bindings, the method has a different signature.

Comment: @cosmarc Here is my version :
```$ ogrinfo --version
GDAL 2.4.2, released 2019/06/28
```

Comment: @the_cheff I had already tried this, and just did it again to make sure, but it returns me the same error :
```---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-03ed6623ff12> in <module>
----> 1 transform.TransformPoint(-17.4380493164062, 14.6951949085676, 0)

Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'CoordinateTransformation_TransformPoint
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the cookbook](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/projection.html#reproject-a-geometry) you are flipping the use of transform and point. You should call transform on the point given the transform, not the other way around. It also seems like you are flipping source and target, but you do that two times, so it will work.

However I believe that `target.ImportFromUrl(path + TIFFFilename)` will not work. Instead you can extract the spatial reference from the geotiff using gdal.

Something like the following should work

```
from osgeo import osr, ogr, gdal

# Extract target reference from the tiff file
ds = gdal.Open(path + TIFFFilename)
target = osr.SpatialReference(wkt=ds.GetProjection())

source = osr.SpatialReference()
source.ImportFromEPSG(4326)

transform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(source, target)

point = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
point.AddPoint(-17.4380493164062, 14.6951949085676)
point.Transform(transform)
print(point.GetX(), point.GetY())
```

This provides you with the coordinates in your geotiffs reference, however this is not pixel coordinates.

To convert the point to pixels you could use something like the following (the minus for the line might have to be flipped, based on where in the world you are)

```
def world_to_pixel(geo_matrix, x, y):
    """
    Uses a gdal geomatrix (gdal.GetGeoTransform()) to calculate
    the pixel location of a geospatial coordinate
    """
    ul_x= geo_matrix[0]
    ul_y = geo_matrix[3]
    x_dist = geo_matrix[1]
    y_dist = geo_matrix[5]
    pixel = int((x - ul_x) / x_dist)
    line = -int((ul_y - y) / y_dist)
    return pixel, line
```

So your final code would look something like

```
from osgeo import osr, ogr, gdal


def world_to_pixel(geo_matrix, x, y):
    """
    Uses a gdal geomatrix (gdal.GetGeoTransform()) to calculate
    the pixel location of a geospatial coordinate
    """
    ul_x= geo_matrix[0]
    ul_y = geo_matrix[3]
    x_dist = geo_matrix[1]
    y_dist = geo_matrix[5]
    pixel = int((x - ul_x) / x_dist)
    line = -int((ul_y - y) / y_dist)
    return pixel, line

# Extract target reference from the tiff file
ds = gdal.Open(path + TIFFFilename)
target = osr.SpatialReference(wkt=ds.GetProjection())

source = osr.SpatialReference()
source.ImportFromEPSG(4326)

transform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(source, target)

point = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
point.AddPoint(-17.4380493164062, 14.6951949085676)
point.Transform(transform)

x, y = world_to_pixel(ds.GetGeoTransform(), point.GetX(), point.GetY())
print(x, y)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply and explanation, i tried to run your code and everything was smooth until the ```point.Transform(transform)``` call.
The error is the following : 
```~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/osgeo/ogr.py in Transform(self, *args)
   7369         OGRERR_NONE on success or an error code.
   7370         """
-> 7371         return _ogr.Geometry_Transform(self, *args)
   7372 
   7373 

TypeError: in method 'Geometry_Transform', argument 2 of type 'OSRCoordinateTransformationShadow *'

``` ....I'm currently trying an alternative with the gdal.Transformer

Comment: It is probably due to the fact that your `target` is not correctly imported. For instance try to replace `target.ImportFromUrl(path + TIFFFilename)` with `target.ImportFromEPSG(4088)` and verify that it works (with wrong transformation though). If you know the target EPSG you can simply insert it. I do not think that importfromurl is doing what you think it does ;-)

Comment: I have updated the code in my answer to extract the Spatial Reference from your geotiff, which is what I think you are trying to do

Comment: I just achieved the same thing after doing some researches ! Thanks a lot for your efforts in helping me. Now i am quite confused because what i am trying to do is find the pixel coordinates of a given position. My method and your do return the same thing but it is definitely not the pixel coordinates of the point.

Comment: That is correct you have just got coordinates in the rasters coordinate system. I have updated my answer, to explain how you can convert that into pixels

Comment: you sir managed to eventually make me understand all this, thanks a lot this is perfect. I was missing some bricks in my understanding.

Comment: Hello, i am currently trying to perform the inverse operation based on the method you described, but the final coordinated are wrong. Could you take a look ? I could edit my initial post with a new section dedicated to pixel to long lat conversion if it is relevant.

Comment: In order to help other readers I think you should ask that as a new question, and post a link to it as a comment here. Then i will be happy to answer it ;-)

Comment: of course ! Here is the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59052516/find-lat-long-coordinates-from-pixel-point-in-geotiff-using-python-and-gdal

Comment: This code worked as is when using a dem in EPSG:4326, however to get it to work with a dem in EPSG:21781+5728, I had to flip `point.AddPoint(long, lat)` to `point.AddPoint(lat, long)`. No idea why...

Comment: @fariadantes In GDAL 3.0 special ordering was introduced for 4326. this issue is for instance mentioned here https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/1546

I do find it to be more confusing than helpful though.

Answer (score 2):

The proposed solution might work in most of the cases as row/column rotation is typically zero, but it should be at least checked or better included:

```py
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal

def world_to_pxl(gt, x, y):
    # 'Affine transformation': W = A * pxl + ul
    # world[2, 1] = a[2, 2] * pxl[2, 1] + upper_left[2,1]
    world = np.array([[x], [y]])  # world coordinates
    upper_left = np.array(
        [
            [gt[0]], [gt[3]]    # upper left corner of image
        ]
    )
    a = np.array([[gt[1], gt[2]],
                  [gt[4], gt[5]]])
    
    # Reformulate: A^-1 * (W - ul) = pxl
    pxl = np.matmul(np.linalg.inv(a), (world - upper_left))
    row = pxl[0]  # x_pixel
    col = pxl[1]  # y_line
    return row, col
```